# How do I click a button with Javascript:void(0) Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I've been struggling and I've tried multiple things. Sorry if my formatting isn't correct but anyway, the element in question that I need to click is:

```
<button href="javascript:void(0)" id="payNewBeneficiary" class="button-new-payee">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                                <div></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h2>Someone new</h2>
                                            <p>Make a once-off payment or pay someone new</p>
                                        </button>
```

So far I've tried finding the element by ID, cssSelector and xpath. I've also tried this

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver); 
act.moveToElement(payNewBeneficiaryButton);
act.click(payNewBeneficiaryButton);
        act.build().perform();
```

As well as this

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('payNewBeneficiary').click()");
```

And this

```
JavascriptExecutor exec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
exec.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", payNewBeneficiaryButton);
```

Comment: You take out your computer mouse, position the pointer just over the element, and you hit the left mouse button. That's how you click a button. Of course, if it's "voided", nothing is ever going to happen when you click it.

Comment: `href` in buttons is a custom attribute, it has no default action.

Comment: I'm kind of struggling trying to understand exactly what you want here.  You getting an error?  Also adeneo is right, if it's "voided" it's never going to do anything when you click it.  What happens when you click it with your mouse?

Comment: Is that entire `button` element clickable? You can tell by inspecting in chrome or firepath or whatever by hovering over the element in the dom and seeing what it covers, and compare that to when your mouse turns into a pointer for what you want to click. My guess is you need to click `div` with class `icon`, or perhaps the text? `#payNewBeneficiary .icon` would be the **css selector**

Comment: @IamBatman When I click it with my mouse it opens up a form that allows you to enter a user's banking details.

Comment: Have you tried .submit()?

Comment: @IamBatman Yes I have.

Comment: Without the full code, I dunno what else "I" or "anyone" else can do for you.  When I copy your code, I can find the element no problem.  As far as I can tell you can't click on a "javascript:void" button or link without using ".submit()". I hope someone can help you or maybe you can provide more information to better assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was that the element was not clickable. I used the following code to scroll down the page first until the element wasn't obstructed.

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(payNewBeneficiaryButton));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",payNewBeneficiaryButton);
payNewBeneficiaryButton.click();
```

Thanks for trying to help guys. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try these

```
driver.findElement(By.css("<one of the below css>")).click()
```

css you can try

```
button#payNewBeneficiary div div
button#payNewBeneficiary div
button#payNewBeneficiary h2
button#payNewBeneficiary p
```

Sometimes the listen may be on a specified child element